# How to make this query with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a base query and need to add a filter for locations.

`Location.parents` is an array of integers.

It works, but it uses 2 queries:

```py
parents_ids = self._db_session.query(Location.parents)\
    .filter(Location.id == location_id)\
    .scalar()

query = query.filter(
    or_(
        BookingItem.location_id == location_id, 
        BookingItem.location_id.in_(parents_ids)
    )
)
```

How can I do this with one query? I tried to use a subquery, but it doesn't work.

```py
parents_ids = self._db_session.query(Location.parents)\
    .filter(Location.id == location_id)\
    .subquery()

query = query.filter(
    or_(
        BookingItem.location_id == location_id, 
        BookingItem.location_id.in_(parents_ids.as_scalar())
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the SQL to look like this:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM booking_item
WHERE location_id = ?
   OR (SELECT location_id = ANY(parents) FROM location WHERE id = ?)
```

Then the related SQLAlchemy would be

```py
parents_ids = self._db_session\
    .query(BookingItem.location_id == Location.parents.any())\
    .filter(Location.id == location_id)\
    .subquery()

query = query.filter(
    or_(
        BookingItem.location_id == location_id, 
        parents_ids.as_scalar()
    )
)
```

---

Another option is to use `UNNEST` to create a list of options:

SQL:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM booking_item
WHERE location_id = ?
   OR location_id IN (SELECT UNNEST(parents) FROM location WHERE id = ?)
```

Then the related SQLAlchemy would be

```py
parents_ids = self._db_session\
    .query(func.unnest(Location.parents))\
    .filter(Location.id == location_id)\
    .subquery()

query = query.filter(
    or_(
        BookingItem.location_id == location_id, 
        BookingItem.location_id.in_(parents_ids.as_scalar())
    )
)
```